# Android Kotlin copy App file to "Files" App through Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have an Android Kotlin app.  I'm using API 27+.  I have a .csv file generated in my app.  I'm trying to write this app created .csv file to the android device "Files" app.

I can create the file in my app's cache directory.  The cache file looks great!

When I use the intent to write the the Files app, a "Files" file is created, but its empty.

What do I need to change to copy my app's .csv file to the "Files" app with data?  If CREATE_DOCUMENT is the wrong intent, which is correct?  If I change the intent type, what changes do I need to make to the manifest/gradle to enable sharing the data.

Code to create a dummy .csv file in my app:

```
private fun downloadFile() {
    val CSV_HEADER = "id,name,address,age"

    val myToyBoxFile = File.createTempFile("MyToyBox", ".csv")
    var fileWriter: FileWriter? = null

    try {
        fileWriter = FileWriter(myToyBoxFile)

        fileWriter.append(CSV_HEADER)
        fileWriter.append('\n')


        fileWriter.append("aaaaa")
        fileWriter.append(',')
        fileWriter.append("bbbbb")
        fileWriter.append(',')
        fileWriter.append("cccccc")
        fileWriter.append(',')
        fileWriter.append("dddddd")
        fileWriter.append('\n')
        println("Write CSV successfully!")

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Writing CSV error!")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    fileWriter!!.close()

    val uriForFile = Uri.fromFile(myToyBoxFile)
    createFile(uriForFile)
}
```

Intent code.

```
val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pickerInitialUri)
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "text/csv"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myToyBox.csv")
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the integration to the 'Files' app to work, but I did get access to the "Share" to work allowing me to email the file.

Most of what is the Android page and its links as well as many stackoverflow pages [Android Secure Fiile Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing)

**High Level**

1. Add the provider to your manifest
2. Add a res -> xml -> file_path document with the file share 'paths' location
3. Write the code to share the file using the 'paths' location

**Detailed Steps**

1. Update the manifest -> application section with the 'provider' details

   <manifest
   ...
   <application
   ...

   ```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAPP.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
   ```
2. Add a res -> xml -> file_path document with the file share 'paths' location

If you don't already have an xml directory/package under the res location (i.e., where your layouts are, add it and add a file.  I called mine file_paths.  You may already have one depending on what you already coded.  I wrote my document to share to the docs/ folder.  This locaiton will be needed in the actual code.

docs/ is located `File(requireContext().filesDir, "docs")`
docs/ is located in the emulator under `data/data/com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAPP/files/docs`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
</paths>
```

3. Write the code to share the file using the 'paths' location and the fileprovider reference

   private fun downloadFile() {

   ```
    val filePath: File = File(requireContext().filesDir, "docs")
    filePath.mkdirs()
    val newFile = File(filePath, "MyToyBox.csv")
    newFile.delete()
    newFile.createNewFile()
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        "com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAP.fileprovider",
        newFile
    )

    val CSV_HEADER = "Series,My Toy Box ID,Debut Year,Phase,Wave,Action Figure Package Name," +
            "Movie Scene," +
            "Estimated New Value,Have the New Figure,Have New Count," +
            "Want the New Figure,Want New Count," +
            "Sell the New Figure,Sell New Count," +
            "Order the New Figure,Order New Count," +
            "Order from Text," +
            "Have the Loose Figure,Have Loose Count" +
            ",Want the Loose Figure,Want Loose Count" +
            ",Sell the Loose Figure,Sell Loose Count" +
            ",Notes" + "\n"

    var fileWriter: FileWriter? = null

    try {
        fileWriter = FileWriter(newFile)

        fileWriter.append(CSV_HEADER)

        figureList.forEach { figure ->

            val specifics = figure.specifics

            val noText = "No"
            val yesText = "Yes"

            val new_haveCount = specifics.new_haveCount.toString()
            val new_wantCount = specifics.new_wantCount.toString()
            val new_sellCount = specifics.new_sellCount.toString()
            val new_orderCount = specifics.new_orderCount.toString()
            val new_orderText = specifics.new_orderText

            val loose_haveCount = specifics.loose_haveCount.toString()
            val loose_wantCount = specifics.loose_wantCount.toString()
            val loose_sellCount = specifics.loose_sellCount.toString()

            // set yes/no text based on count
            val new_haveTheFigure = if (specifics.new_haveCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_wantTheFigure = if (specifics.new_wantCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_sellTheFigure = if (specifics.new_sellCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_orderTheFigure = if (specifics.new_orderCount == 0) noText else yesText

            val loose_haveTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_haveCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val loose_wantTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_wantCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val loose_sellTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_sellCount == 0) noText else yesText

            val notes = specifics.notes

            // formatted value
            var newValueString = kUnknownMTBValue
            val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
            currencyFormat.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            currencyFormat.currency = Currency.getInstance("USD")
            if (figure.saleSummary != null) {
                val formattedValue =
                    currencyFormat.format(figure.saleSummary!!.estimatedValueMean).toString()
                newValueString =
                    context?.getString(R.string.saleSummaryValueCount,
                        formattedValue,
                        figure.saleSummary!!.saleCount).toString()
            }

            // need to escape , with \" in front and back, such as in wave and names.
            val row: String = "\"${figure.series.seriesName}\"," +
                    "${figure.figureUniqueId}," +
                    "${figure.debutYear}," +
                    "\"${figure.phase}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.wave}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.figurePackageName}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.scene}\"," +
                    "\"$newValueString\"," +
                    "$new_haveTheFigure,$new_haveCount," +
                    "$new_wantTheFigure,$new_wantCount," +
                    "$new_sellTheFigure,$new_sellCount," +
                    "$new_orderTheFigure,$new_orderCount," +
                    "\"$new_orderText\"" +
                    ",$loose_haveTheFigure,$loose_haveCount," +
                    "$loose_wantTheFigure,$loose_wantCount," +
                    "$loose_sellTheFigure,$loose_sellCount," +
                    "\"$notes\"" + "\n"

            fileWriter.append(row)
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Writing CSV error!")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    fileWriter!!.close()

    createFile(contentUri)
   ```

   }

   private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {

   ```
    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pickerInitialUri)
        type = "text/plain"
        setDataAndType(pickerInitialUri, requireContext().contentResolver.getType(pickerInitialUri))
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "My Toy Box"))
   ```

   }